# sensors-detect does not detect

Tags: debian-squeeze, sensors

I am trying to run sensors-detect in Debian6 64 bits and I get:
Sorry, no sensors were detected. Either your system has no sensors, or they are not supported, or they are connected to an I2C or SMBus adapter that is not supported.

Sensors applet is correctly running as well as sensor cpu

```
root@debian:/# dmesg | grep -i error
[    0.558964] ACPI Error (psargs-0359): [RAMB] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND
[    7.537292] PM: Error -22 checking image file
[    9.581500] nouveau: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -22

root@debian:/# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 1244 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation Device 0bee (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB Controller: Device 1b21:1042
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Device 1b21:1080 (rev 01)
```

---

**I did update the appropriated file with dl.lm-sensors.org/lm-sensors/files/sensors-detect. Now sensors-detect is detecting some sensors**

```
root@debian:/# sensors-detect
# sensors-detect revision 6057 (2012-06-01 17:47:27 +0200)
# Board: ASUSTeK Computer INC. P8Z68-V LX

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no):  
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               Yes
Found `Nuvoton NCT6776F Super IO Sensors'                   Success!
    (address 0x290, driver `w83627ehf')
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): 
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (yes/NO): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel Cougar Point (PCH)
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 0 at 1:00.0 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at 1:00.0 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Client found at address 0x4a
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM77'...                No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7410'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7411'...                     No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS1621/DS1631'...         No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM73'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM92'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM76'...                No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Client found at address 0x4b
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM77'...                No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7410'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7411'...                     No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS1621/DS1631'...         No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM92'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM76'...                No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7481'...                     No

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 6 at 1:00.0 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `w83627ehf':
  * ISA bus, address 0x290
    Chip `Nuvoton NCT6776F Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Do you want to overwrite /etc/sysconfig/lm_sensors? (YES/no): 
Copy prog/init/lm_sensors.init to /etc/init.d/lm_sensors
for initialization at boot time.
You should now start the lm_sensors service to load the required
kernel modules.

Unloading i2c-dev... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

---

**There is not prog/init/lm_sensors.init, I did not copy anything to /etc/init.d/lm_sensors. Probably I don't know how to load. i2c-dev & cpuid. After running sensors-detect, I just get the following output at sensors:**

```
root@debian:/# sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +27.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)                  
temp2:       +29.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
```

---

**It seems that I have to load w83627ehf & coretemp, they exist somewhere but they are not configured**

```
root@debian:/# modprobe -l | grep w83627ehf
kernel/drivers/hwmon/w83627ehf.ko
root@debian:/# modprobe -l | grep coretemp
kernel/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.ko
root@debian:/# lsmod | grep coretemp
root@debian:/# lsmod | grep w83627ehf
```

---

**I have manually added to /etc/modules (/etc/modules.conf does not exist)**

```
#loop was already
loop
coretemp
w83627ehf
```

---

**I am trying to follow: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto**

```
root@debian:/# service module-init-tools restart
Loading kernel modules...done.
root@debian:/# sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +27.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)                  
temp2:       +29.8°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
```

---

**I cannot add both modules with modprobe**

```
root@debian:/# modprobe w83627ehf
FATAL: Error inserting w83627ehf (/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/hwmon/w83627ehf.ko): No such device
root@debian:/# modprobe coretemp
FATAL: Error inserting coretemp (/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.ko): No such device
```

---

**But they exist at such folder**

```
root@debian:/# ls /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/hwmon/
abituguru3.ko  adm1026.ko  adt7473.ko       dme1737.ko   gl518sm.ko    ibmpex.ko     lm75.ko  lm90.ko     max1619.ko     smsc47m192.ko   vt1211.ko     w83793.ko
abituguru.ko   adm1029.ko  adt7475.ko       ds1621.ko    gl520sm.ko    it87.ko       lm77.ko  lm92.ko     max6650.ko     smsc47m1.ko     vt8231.ko     w83l785ts.ko
ad7414.ko      adm1031.ko  applesmc.ko      f71805f.ko   hdaps.ko      k10temp.ko    lm78.ko  lm93.ko     pc87360.ko     thmc50.ko   w83627ehf.ko  w83l786ng.ko
ad7418.ko      adm9240.ko  asb100.ko        f71882fg.ko  hp_accel.ko   k8temp.ko     lm80.ko  lm95241.ko  pc87427.ko     tmp401.ko   w83627hf.ko   wm831x-hwmon.ko
adcxx.ko       ads7828.ko  asus_atk0110.ko  f75375s.ko   hwmon-vid.ko  lis3lv02d.ko  lm83.ko  ltc4215.ko  pcf8591.ko     tmp421.ko   w83781d.ko    wm8350-hwmon.ko
adm1021.ko     adt7462.ko  atxp1.ko     fschmd.ko    i5k_amb.ko    lm63.ko       lm85.ko  ltc4245.ko  sis5595.ko     via686a.ko  w83791d.ko
adm1025.ko     adt7470.ko  coretemp.ko      g760a.ko     ibmaem.ko     lm70.ko       lm87.ko  max1111.ko  smsc47b397.ko  via-cputemp.ko  w83792d.ko
```

---

**Seems that Alias was missing, cannot find alias of modules**

```
root@debian:/# modprobe -c | grep w83627ehf
root@debian:/# modprobe -c | grep coretemp
root@debian:/#
```

---

**There is information about modules**

```
root@debian:/# modinfo coretemp
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel Core temperature monitor
author:         Rudolf Marek <r.marek@assembler.cz>
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.32-5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
root@debian:/# modinfo w83627ehf
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/hwmon/w83627ehf.ko
license:        GPL
description:    W83627EHF driver
author:         Jean Delvare <khali@linux-fr.org>
depends:        hwmon-vid
vermagic:       2.6.32-5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force_id:Override the detected device ID (ushort)
root@debian:/# 

root@debian:/# modinfo loop
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/block/loop.ko
alias:          block-major-7-*
license:        GPL
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.32-5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           max_loop:Maximum number of loop devices (int)
parm:           max_part:Maximum number of partitions per loop device (int)
```

---

**https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=250561**

```
root@debian:/# grep -v ^# /etc/sysconfig/lm_sensors

HWMON_MODULES="coretemp w83627ehf"


MODULE_0=coretemp
MODULE_1=w83627ehf
root@debian:/# modprobe -l | grep -i cpuid
kernel/arch/x86/kernel/cpuid.ko
root@debian:/# lsmod | grep cpuid
root@debian:/# lsmod | grep i2c-dev
root@debian:/# modprobe -l | grep -i i2c-dev
kernel/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.ko
root@debian:/#
```

Comment: I am using the same module for reading sensors on an Intel DQ57TM mainboard. Some time ago, when I was running kernel 2.6.32 on Ubuntu 10.04 I failed to get it working (showing some, but wrong output). Upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 and kernel 3.2 later somehow fixed it and things work out of the box. Could you try a more recent Linux (Debian backports) kernel? Your hardware will probably benefit performance wise too (Sandy Bridge is relatively recent compared to 2.6.32).

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the `coretemp` module does not support the Core i7 or later processors until kernel version `2.6.35` <sup>[(Source)](http://lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices)</sup>

Since you're running `2.6.32-5`, I would try updating your kernel.